# unable to access Jenkins installed on ubuntu 18.10, browser says " xxxxx took too long to respond"

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

a question from a beginner.

I have just installed Jenkins on:

- Ubuntu 18.10 minimal - google cloud Platform
- Java 8 installed
- UFW  configured to allow traffic on port 80 from anywhere

when accessing it from the client computer browser through the internet; it says `<server IP address> took too long to respond`

running **`netstat -apn|grep 80;`** i get:

```
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.3:58216        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.3:58214        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.3:58212        169.254.169.254:80      CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 10.142.0.3:58218        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

**`$ ps aux|grep jenkins`**

```
jenkins   6939  0.0  0.4  46188  7856 ?        Ss   11:59   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
jenkins   6950  0.0  0.1 149060  2744 ?        S    11:59   0:00 (sd-pam)
jenkins   6978  0.0  0.0   4684   156 ?        S    11:59   0:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=jenkins --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins --output=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --pidfile=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid -- /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8081
jenkins   6979  0.1  9.9 2437292 172520 ?      Sl   11:59   0:28 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8081
root     12198  0.0  0.2  31912  4300 pts/1    S    16:45   0:00 sudo /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
root     12199  0.9  8.7 2437292 151936 pts/1  Sl   16:45   0:11 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
xcvbtr+ 12375  0.0  0.0   5016   896 pts/1    S+   17:05   0:00 grep --color=auto jenkins
```

Comment: Jenkins opens port 8080 by default, try browsing to http://jenkins:8080 , Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i needed to allow traffic not only from my instance firewall, but also from the cloud platform.